# Powershell ICACLS to change permissions on a file

Tags: windows, powershell, file-permissions, icacls

Basically what I'm trying to do is push a txt file out to a list of remote PCs and then change the permissions on that file for the local users group to only have read and execute. (I gave up trying to push the file out while retaining permissions). PC names are listed on separate lines in `ComputerNames.txt` file.

Here is what I have:

```cs
$computers = Get-Content "C:\ComputerNames.txt"
$fileToCopy = "C:\newFile.txt"
foreach ($computer in $Computers) {
    # Copy file to remote PC
    Copy-Item -Path $fileToCopy -Destination "\\$computer\C`$\HOMEWARE\"
    # Reset current permissions on file
    icacls \\$computer\C$\HOMEWARE\newFile.txt /reset
    # Grant Read / Execute
    icacls \\$computer\C$\HOMEWARE\newFile.txt /grant:r "USERS:(OI)(CI)RX"
}
pause
```

It seems like it is copying the file over and permissions get reset but it doesn't strip away anything, users still have write and special permissions.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Silly question, but if you run the ICACLS manually, does it work as expected?

Comment: Copying a file typically preserves file attributes, extended attributes, security resource attributes, and alternate data streams. Discretionary and system access control lists (i.e. DACL and SACL) are inherited from the target directory. If you reset the file security, it's just reapplying the inheritable entries. Instead use `/inheritance:d`, which disables inheritance (i.e. protects the DACL) and explicitly sets the formerly inherited entries. Use `/grant:r` to replace explicit entries for "Users" and "Authenticated Users", but use the aliases `*BU` and `*AU` instead of localized names.

Comment: Nope, i get "Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files", but the file still has all permissions checked for the users group

Comment: Also, there's no need to add Object Inherit (OI) and Container Inherit (CI) flags to the ACE for a file. Those flags are meant for directories.

Comment: @ErykSun You're the only one who seems to know about these wonderful locale-independent aliases like *BU and *AU.  Do you know where these aliases documented?

Answer (score 1):

`/grant:r` would only replace existing *explicit* permissions for the given user or group. It doesn't touch inherited permissions. Object inheritance (OI) and container inheritance (CI) only make sense when dealing with folders. Nothing is going to inherit permissions from a file. Also, just disabling inheritance (`/inheritance:d`) does not suffice, you need to remove the existing permissions as well (`/inheritance:r`).

This should do what you want:

```
icacls \\$computer\C$\HOMEWARE\newFile.txt /reset
icacls \\$computer\C$\HOMEWARE\newFile.txt /inheritance:r /grant "Users:rx"
```

Note that this will remove *all* inherited permissions from the file, which may inhibit backup and other system management operations. As eryksun pointed out in the comments it might be better to just disable inheritance (turning inherited permissions into explicit permissions) and then replace the User ACE.

```
icacls \\$computer\C$\HOMEWARE\newFile.txt /reset
icacls \\$computer\C$\HOMEWARE\newFile.txt /inheritance:d /grant:r "Users:rx"
```

If you still want inherited permissions removed instead of converted to explicit permissions I would strongly recommend to additionally grant access for administrators and SYSTEM.

```
icacls \\$computer\C$\HOMEWARE\newFile.txt /reset
icacls \\$computer\C$\HOMEWARE\newFile.txt /inheritance:r /grant "Users:rx" "Administrators:f" "system:f"
```

Comment: Removing all inherited permissions would remove access for SYSTEM and administrators, and whatever else is inherited by default for files in the parent directory. `/inheritance:d` is perfectly fine when combined with `/grant:r`.

Comment: Also, doing a  `/reset` for a newly created file is generally pointless. Unless it was created with an explicit security descriptor (doubtful for a generic copy), it's already using inherited permissions.

Comment: Also, do not use localized names such as "Users". Use SDDL aliases such as `*BU` (or SID strings if you're somewhat masochistic).

Comment: @eryksun My understanding was that the OP wanted all inherited permissions removed and only permissions for the User group applied. And personally I don't see anyting wrong with using localized names as long as your infrastructure is homogenous enough for that. I always found dealing with both SDDL and SIDs a pain in the rear.

Comment: Common SDDL account aliases are easy to remember, and a universal shorthand: WD (everyone/world), SY (system), LS (local service), and NS (network service), BA (administrators), BU (users), DA (domain administrators), DU (domain users), AU (authenticated users), IU (interactive), NU (network), SU (service), AN (anonymous), CO (creator owner), and OW (owner rights). On the other hand, SDDL rights for files are difficult for me to remember since they're based on Active Directory rights that map arbitrarily to file rights. Thankfully icacls.exe doesn't use SDDL rights.

Comment: I'd upvote your answer if I thought the question belonged here. This should be asked on Super User.